# I am trying to get centOS pagespeed apache2 module to run with SSL but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: virtualhost, https, httpd, mod-pagespeed, page-speed

I have installed pagespeed module for httpd on centOS, finally I got it to work with http, but I still haven't managed to get it directing for ssl's, I've added the ssl cert dir path and .pem path, and from what I can tell have written everything else right. I include the ModPagespeed on 3 times, 2 times in the pagespeed.conf file, once at the top and there is another one a little further down. Then at the top of the vhost.conf as well.

The real settings are set in the vhost.conf file, is this wrong?

I have a server which hosts a few websites, the HTTP sites work, but not the HTTPS ones.

Have a look:

```
ModPagespeed on
# Attempt to load mod_version if it wasn't loaded or compiled in (eg on Debian)
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
  LoadModule version_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
</IfModule>

<IfVersion < 2.4>
  LoadModule pagespeed_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_pagespeed.so
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4.2>
  # As default pagespeed.conf configuration uses old-style ACLs using
  # 'allow' and 'deny', we load mod_access_compat in Apache 2.4. If that's a
  # problem, the blocks using that can be converted to the newer 'Require'
  # syntax.
  <IfModule !access_compat_module>
    LoadModule access_compat_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.$
  </IfModule>

  LoadModule pagespeed_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_pagespeed_ap24.so
</IfVersion>

# Only attempt to load mod_deflate if it hasn't been loaded already.
<IfModule !mod_deflate.c>
 LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_deflate.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    # Turn on mod_pagespeed. To completely disable mod_pagespeed, you
    # can set this to "off".
    ModPagespeed on

ModPagespeed on
ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
ModPagespeedFileCachePath "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/"

# Image Filters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images,insert_image_dimensions,inline_images,$

# CSS Filters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,move_css_above_scripts,combine_css,inline$

# JS Filters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript,canonicalize_javascript_libraries,$

# Misc Filters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,trim_urls,remove_quotes,insert_dn$

# Direct Apache to send all HTML output to the mod_pagespeed
# output handler.
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
ModPagespeedPreserveUrlRelativity on
ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable

ModPagespeedSslCertDirectory /etc/pki/tls/certs
ModPagespeedSslCertFile /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName default:80
        ServerAdmin ireply@myleisure.com.au
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

</VirtualHost>

ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain "http://myleisure.com.au" "https://www.myleisure.co$

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName myleisure.com.au
        ServerAlias myleisure.com.au
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myleisure.com.au
        Redirect permanent / https
```

Comment: bump please help